# Проблема PS и рефлектора

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, рефлексия, jetbrains

Мне почему-то вдруг стало интересно: "А что у класса [`System.Management.Automatization.PowerShell`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=pscore-6.2.0) (путь к dll - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v*версия PS*\System.Management.Automatization.dll`) творится в голове?".

> Не важно зачем он - важно что он.

Я - как истинный пират - взял рефлектор от [`JetBrains`](https://www.jetbrains.com/) ([`dotPeek`](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)) и вскрыл эту библиотеку. И как оказалось, **ВСЕ** методы либо пустые, либо, если они возвращают значение, содержат один коммент: "`Stub method (only 'ret' instruction)`", - я так понял это какие-то методы-заглушки. И это абсолютно о **ВСЕХ** классах.

---

Что это такое и как вообще компилируется "2-й тип (с комментарием)" метода? Что такое и зачем нужны методы-заглушки? Это шифровка dll, баг рефлектора или что?

Comment: А вообще зачем их дизасемблировать, если powershell core лежит с открытыми исходниками?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это так называемая `reference assembly`. В них нет имплементаций методов, и только публичные классы. Их придумали для случая, когда одна и та же длл-ка может иметь разные версии (для .NET 4.0, 4.5, 4.6 и т.д.). На этапе сборки ваш проект ссылается на `reference assembly`, а в рантайме уже ищется нужная длл в системе.

Детальней здесь: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/history/evolution-of-design-time-assemblies.md#using-reference-assemblies

Если вы хотите посмотреть на .NET Framework версию `System.Management.Automatization.PowerShell` ищите ее в GAC.

Answer (score 2):

Это [metadata-only сборка](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/refout.md). В нет реального кода, и есть только то количество метаданных, которого хватает для компиляции ссылающегося на эту сборку кода.

Реальная сборка с кодом лежит в GAC (например, в C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll), и при запуске подтягивается вместо Reference Assembly.